# Is there a way to load very low-res tiles in mapbox/leaflet instead of displaying white tile while loading?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

The default behaviour of mapbox/leaflet (2.4.0/0.7.7) is to display a white tile when you pan the map. Even when you pan back to an area that was just visible. That is annoying.

I wonder if there is a way to force leaflet/mapbox to either:

- cache a couple of tiles for re-use in panning/zooming operations
- load a really low res tile before the real high-res tile is loaded

Comment: This is strange. I only see the white background one using this example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/. (without leaving the page that is)

Comment: I am seeing that with the mapbox version above

Answer (score 1):

> cache a couple of tiles for re-use in panning/zooming operations

This plugin: https://github.com/TolonUK/Leaflet.EdgeBuffer pre-loads tiles outside the current viewport which works as cache for the panning operation

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do about it.

You want to cache a couple of tiles for re-use in panning/zooming operations.
This is already done by your browser. Just turn on your browser's console and check out the network traffic: no request to the server when you display tiles again (panning or zooming).

You want to load a really low res tile before the real high-res tile is loaded. Tiles are already lightweight images (under 30k). Having another set of images with a few K less won't change the Time to Last Byte.

Comment: While the tiles are not reloaded from the network they are still not instantly available and therefore I see white background, while (a previously loaded and chached) tile is being loaded

Answer (score 0):

> load a really low res tile before the real high-res tile is loaded

While this is possible, it would require a major code refactor to be implemented, and it's likely not to be done anytime soon.

Things like [loading more tiles than needed just to show them quicker when panning](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/4614) are into consideration.